# Find out all the minimum in the curve

Tags: python, scipy

I need to find out all the minimums in the curve but I am only the local minimums.

```py
counts = np.sum(chunked_images[2]<chunked_images[2].max()/2., axis=1)

N = 15

cumsum, moving_aves = [0], []

for i, x in enumerate(counts, 1):    
    cumsum.append(cumsum[i-1] + x)

    if i>=N:
        moving_ave = (cumsum[i] - cumsum[i-N])/N
        #can do stuff with moving_ave here
        moving_aves.append(moving_ave)

moving_aves = np.array(moving_aves)
a = argrelextrema(moving_aves, np.less)
print(a)
```

Result: `(array([611, 628, 651]),)`
But these are not all the minimums:

[image: img]

Comment: So you want to find all the local minima and as well as global ones?

Comment: The question has nothing to do with plotting but with numerical approaches. I am removing the `matplotlib` tag

Comment: @AmitAmola I want all the minimums including the valley where the values are zero.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is to apply the definition of a local minimum.

An index `i` of `counts` is a local minimum iff:

```
counts[i-1] > counts[i] and counts[i+1] > counts[i]
```

Comment: This is right in spirit but a little too simple for this case. On the graph there are several plateaus where `counts` is a constant 0 for several  consecutive points, for each example near 675 and 750. Your algorithm will not catch these.

Comment: I disagree, replace `>` by `>=`

Comment: Ah, but then the weakly monotonic sequence [2, 1, 1, 1, 0] will falsely detect a minima!

Comment: I am unable to catch the valley with constant zero as stated by @olooney

Comment: @olooney : the second 1 IS a local minima. However, for the boudary points of the interval the conditions are `counts[0]<=counts[1]` and `counts[-1]<=counts [-2]`

Comment: @Aditya, even with `<=` instead of `<`? I'm surprised. Maybe these points are not exactly zero ?

Comment: These points are exactly zero that I have checked. Well I have got a solution to this problem, I first applied butterworth filter to the 'counts' I calculated so now I am getting a smooth curve. After this the argrelextrema is giving all the points I require along with some garbage points that I can easily segregate

Comment: Can you send me the data please ?

Comment: Actually I am working on images containing handwritten text, so this graph is the average intensity of pixels in a row of the image. So when there is gap between the lines, there is no pixel present, hence I am getting a zero there. You can check it on any image you want.

Comment: Can you process the data and send it ?